# Access of label text in the other class

Tags: iphone

I got two `viewcontrollers.  --> AViewController,BViewController`

`AViewController` need to create an object of `BViewController`.
And `presentmodalcontroller`: to go to the `BViewController`.

And `BViewController`   need to create an object of the `AViewController`   as well, so that is can update the label text inside `BViewController  's` method.

Has try import in `AViewController`   in `BViewController`  . error come out. 
unknown type name'`ViewController`', did you mean '`UIViewController`'?

If i want access the AViewController   too, how do i solve this.

Anyone out there can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: since you mentioned update... is it that u want to update the label text of previous AViewController from which u navigated to this BViewController or the new AViewController?

Comment: it is the previous AViewController. thats only two controllers,A and B. BViewController update AViewController label text. AViewController use to navigate to BViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your BViewController.h

```
#import AViewcontroller.h

@property(nonatomic,retain) AViewcontroller* aViewcontroller;
```

In your BViewController.m

```
@synthesis aViewcontroller;
```

Then in your AViewcontroller.m where you create your BViewcontroller object lets say bViewcontroller

```
bViewcontroller.aViewcontroller=self;
//then navigate to bViewcontroller
```

Then you can update the previous AViewController's label text inside BViewController  's method.

```
self.aViewcontroller.label_you_want_to_update.text=@"your_text_here";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this part bViewcontroller.aViewcontroller=self;
//then navigate to bViewcontroller  do i need to create BViewController object in the AViewController.h

Comment: Ya you need to create but you can create it anywhere either in .h or .m file.for eg In AViweController import BViewController and just before this code " bViewcontroller.aViewcontroller=self " create a BViewController object say bViewController.

Comment: how about if i have a one more CViewcontroller. AViewController is the main view to navigate to BViewController or CViewController. is it the same? cos i can't do that. when i want click to navigate to the CViewController ,the application shut down itself. there is no single error in compile, i do not know why? do you know?

Comment: Its hard to give the exact solution without seeing your actual code... anyways did you do the allocation for CViewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

In your header of BViewController, before the @interface, put:

```
@class AViewController;
```

This will let you declare an instance of AViewController type in BViewController.  In the .m file of BViewController, #import AViewcontroller.h

Comment: that no error, but i still cannot change the label text of AViewController in the BViewController method.

Comment: ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    
   IBOutlet UILabel * label2;
    NSTimer *singaporeTicker;
   SecondViewController *secondView;
}
-(IBAction)addbutton2:(id)sender;
property (nonatomic,retain) SecondViewController *secondView;
property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * label2;

end

Comment: ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

interface ViewController ()

end

implementation ViewController

synthesize label2;
synthesize secondView;


-(IBAction)addbutton2:(id)sender{
    if (self.secondView == nil){
      
        SecondViewController *tmpView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.secondView = tmpView;
        [tmpView release];
    }
  
    self.secondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];
}

Comment: SecondViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
class ViewController;

interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    
    
    ViewController *viewcon;
}
-(IBAction)secondbutton:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender;

property (retain, nonatomic) ViewController *viewcon;


end

Comment: SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

interface SecondViewController ()

end

implementation SecondViewController

synthesize viewcon;

-(IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
}

-(IBAction)secondbutton:(id)sender{
    
NSString * hello= @"hello1";
viewcon.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hello];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: above are the problem i encounter..sry the "@" i never put in my code because this system do not allow me to put comment if i put. The #import and @class show no error. but the label in ViewController still cant be change in the SecondVIewController. help help