# Access the controller of parentviewcontroller from childviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

I am having code in which I have added one childviewcontroller using addsubview.
Example:

```
Chidviewcontroller *child=[Chidviewcontroller alloc]intwithnibname:child....];
[parentviewcontroller.view addsubview:child.view];
```

Now the problem is that when I am working in childviewcontroller:
it is not allowed to access any of the parentviewcontroller's object in childviewcontroller
Even not allowed to import the Parentviewcontrollerr.h file
it showed an error: `-UnknownTypeName`

I have read [this links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368757/setting-property-value-of-parent-viewcontroller-class-from-child-viewcontroller).

But it is still not allowed me to import and make the object of parentviewcontroller
Please help me how to resolve this and do this

Comment: Why dont you navigate to your childview instead or adding it as subView?

Answer (score 0):

This might help [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208730/1357776), difference is that here it navigates to childview whereas you sub added the child

Answer (score 0):

u need to navigate to the child class instead of adding it as a subview. 
still if u want to use it as a subview, u need to use delegates to call the methods of the parent class. Let me know if u understood my point of view

hope it helps. happy coding :)